# Как исправить ошибку при установке psycopg2 через pip?

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, pip, psycopg2

Поменял компьютер, теперь не могу установить psycopg2. PostgreSQL версии 12.1 установлен.

```py
Collecting psycopg2
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/84/d7/6a93c99b5ba4d4d22daa3928b983cec66df4536ca50b22ce5dcac65e4e71/psycopg2-2.8.4.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info
    writing pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'

    Error: pg_config executable not found.

    pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
    containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
    option:

        python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

    or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

    If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
    'psycopg2-binary' package instead.

    For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
    <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html>).


    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dksaofgo\psycopg2\
```

Пытался сделать по инструкции http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#install-from-source

```
$ export PATH=/usr/lib/postgresql/X.Y/bin/:$PATH
```

Писал что "export" не является внутренней или внешней командой. Попробовал без export. Терминал просто проглотил эту команду и потом сам pip перестал быть внутренней или внешней командой. Как это исправить? Может что еще установить надо? Версия Python 3.8.0 Пользуюсь Windows 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pip install psycopg2-binary - это в принципе и установщик пишет.

Comment: Ну да, что через pip install psycopg2-binary, что и просто pip install psycopg2

Comment: согласно https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/990: проапргейдить пип, затем pip install psycopg2-binary --no-cache-dir